# How to concatenate a selection of sqlite columns spread over multiple tables?

Tags: sqlite, concatenation

I am aware that you can concatenate multiple columns within a single table with a query like this:

```
SELECT ( column1 || column2 || column3 || ... ) AS some_name FROM some_table
```

Is it possible to concatenate **columns** from **multiple tables** with a **single sqlite query**?

Very simple example -  Two tables and the result:

```
        Table1              |           Table2          |         Result
  Col1          Col2        |            Col3           |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   A             B          |             C             |           ABC
```

If this is possible, what would the query be?

I can always manually concatenate multiple single table concatenation results, but having sqlite do all the work would be great:)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT a.col1 || a.col2 ||  b.col3 AS 'SUM'
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.id = b.id;
```

In where you have top mention the joining condition between the tables

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/3b3fe/2)